# How do I stop onclick from 'bubbling', that is parent's onclick triggering when child is clicked without using the Event interface?

Tags: javascript, html

This question is not a duplicate because I want a solution that does not use Event interface or stuff from React or JQuery. This is because I like the normal onclick system as is, and don't want to change.

I'm using basic JavaScript to create interactivity on a web page. I'm trying to make it such that whenever certain textual elements are clicked, they change color. (Why? Because I'm just experimenting with stuff.) I'm pretty close to having the behavior I'm looking for, but I'm having trouble with a certain edge case. So you see, I have an array called `selectElements` which contains elements of certain tag names. It contains all `<p>` elements and all `<strong>` elements. Well, there are cases where `<strong>` elements are children of `<p>` elements. That is, something like this: `<p>text text <strong>important text</strong> text</p>`. I want the behavior to be such that when the mouse clicks over 'important text', only 'important text' changes color. Here's my code:

```
selectElements.forEach(elem => {
    function change() {
        if (elem.style.color == 'red') {
            elem.style.color = 'blue';
        } else {
            elem.style.color = 'red';
        }
    }
    elem.onclick = change;
});
```

I have seen references to Event.stopPropagation() but to use that I would need to implement my code with the Event interface. I want to just use the normal Element.onclick property. Can this be done?, and of course if it can, I'd like to know how.

So in summary, I want clicking on `<strong>` enclosed text to change that text's color but not the surrounding text in the `<p>` element, and I don't want to use Event interface.

Comment: _"I want a solution that does not use Event interface or stuff from React or JQuery."_ - I think you misunderstand what the term "Event interface" means...

Comment: _"I want the behavior to be such that when the mouse clicks over 'important text', only 'important text' changes color. Here's my code:"_ - you don't need **any** JS for that - you can do it entirely with CSS and trigger elements or the interaction pseudoclasses.

Comment: `elem.onclick = change;` <-- Don't do this. Use `addEventListener` instead. By overwriting the (legacy) `onclick` property (without even saving the previous binding) you'll break things - as well as lose the ability to specify event-listener options, which you can _only_ do with `addEventListener`.

Comment: _"I have seen references to Event.stopPropagation() but to use that I would need to implement my code with the Event interface."_ - You misunderstand how the DOM works...

Comment: @Dai I saw this code on the Codecademy course I'm taking. Here: ```let element = document.querySelector('button');

element.onclick = function() { 
  element.style.backgroundColor = 'blue' 
}; ``` Is that wrong?

Comment: It's not "wrong" (because it will "work" - in isolation) - but it's still _decades_ out of date - and not appropriate in modern JS.

Comment: @Dai Hmmm interesting. Do you have any suggestions about where I can find modern conventions for JS?

Comment: **Good (authoritative) resources**: WHATWG, W3.org, Mozilla MDN, Google [web.dev](https://web.dev). CanIUse.com, and sites in that ecosystem - while you should _actively avoid_ non-authoritative content-farm sites like GeeksForGeeks, W3Schools, etc - my personal heuristic is to avoid any website with "free code" or "tutorials" in its domain-name.

Comment: @Dai Wow that's the kind of stuff you don't hear as a student. GeeksForGeeks and W3Schools have been my go-tos. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Why can't you just add `e` here `function change(e) {` and call `e.stopPropagation`?